# Howto build mkl_tiny?

Tags: intel-mkl, openvino, intel-dnn

OpenVINO has some 30MB `libmkl_tiny_tbb.so`, which is "The special version of MKL dynamic library packed specially to use within Inference Engine library.", as stated in `version.txt`.

MKL-DNN has 125MB `libmklml_gnu.so`. Is there a way to build a ~30MB file from [MKL-DNN git hub repo](https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you also posted this it the [Intel/MKL Github](https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn/issues/674) project and the answer is "no."  So I'm linking to that so others who might have the same question can get to the answer.

mkl_tiny is built using Custom DLL builder. The size of the resulting library depends on how many symbols you put in it. IIRC, mkl_tiny has only gemm and maybe very few extra functions, while mklml has many more functions from BLAS, some LAPACK functions, and even functions from VML/VSL domain.